# Cannot receive SMS on Android Second Profile

Tags: notifications, sms

I have a OnePlus 10 Pro with Android 14, with the second profile for work use.

I have never been able to receive SMS on the second profile, which is a pain in the butt to say the least, like getting confirming notifications from online verification etc.  Does anyone know a work around that that?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: That is the way Google designed it. See section "Send or receive a text message" on https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/6275589?hl=en